# Why can't I bind a function using .bind the same way with as command flag in a list of buttons in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to bind a lambda to a button with a different event. However, the interpreter is saying
`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Event`
If I replace `buttons_list[z].bind("<Button-3>", lambda i=z: print(myList[i]))` with `buttons_list[z].bind("<Button-3>", lambda i: print(myList[z]))` it prints `no` regardless of the button pressed. When replacing the line with `buttons_list[z].bind("<Button-3>", print(myList[z]))`, it prints them in order at the beginning of the program only, not upon right click (as expected). So why don't `buttons_list.append(tk.Button(self.root, text="Click here" + str(z), command=lambda e=z:print(myList[e])))` and `buttons_list[z].bind("<Button-3>", lambda i=z: print(myList[i]))` behave identically?

```
import tkinter as tk

myList = ["foo", 'bar', 'no']


class TestClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.num = 0
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.make_buttons()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def make_buttons(self):
        buttons_list = []
        for z in range(len(myList)):
            buttons_list.append(
                tk.Button(self.root, text="Click here" + str(z), command=lambda e=z: print(myList[e])))
            buttons_list[z].bind("<Button-3>", lambda i=z: print(myList[i]))
            buttons_list[z].pack()


p = TestClass()
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly your question is. You need `lambda event, i=z: print(myList[i])` though. If tkinter is passing an event to the callback, you need to have an argument for it to place it in, as well as the `i=z` defaulting parameter to get around late binding (I'm assuming that's why you're doing that).

Comment: What I'm asking is why aren't the command= and .bind don't behave the same and how to fix it.

Comment: well to fix something that is probably intended You would have to edit the source file

Comment: okay fine, but is there any was to get them to behave identically?

Comment: I have very little experience with tkinter but from your description, one callback mechanism supplies an event object when calling the callback, the other one doesn't. It's unlikely that there's a way to have the behave them same. You could write up a wrapper function that accepts a function, and returns a function that ignores arguments given to it, then give that as the callback. Then it wouldn't matter whi h mechanism you use.

Comment: Okay then, I try to see if that works

Comment: `def ignore_args(f): return lambda *_: f()`. Then `command=ignore_args(lambda i=z: print(i))`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate that means you have a `lambda` in a `lambda`. I think that's very bad practise.

Comment: @TheLizzard That's highly debatable. It will have a small overhead, as all function calls do. Naively wrapping functions like this also prevents you from accessing Meta information about inner functions, but that's unlikely to be an issue here.

Comment: @Carcigenicate the problem isn't speed. The problem is that it over complicates the problem. If bugs appear, it will be very hard to track down.

Comment: @TheLizzard Idk if this really adds any complexity that would make debugging more difficult. At worst, it's a custom construct that someone may need to understand, but documentation can solve that. Functions similar to this come standard in some functional languages. Yes, in this case, it's better to simply fix the callback parameter list. I made that suggestion since they seemed to want a solution that worked regardless of context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
class TestClass:
    ...
    def make_buttons(self):
        buttons_list = []
        for z in range(len(myList)):
            button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Click here " + str(z), command=lambda z=z: print(myList[z]))
            buttons_list.append(button)
            button.bind("<Button-3>", lambda event, i=z: print(myList[i]))
            button.pack()
```

The problem is that when executing the `command` parameter tkinter doesn't give it an argument. `.bind`'s command is executed with an argument (an event).

Comment: This worked, thank you so much! Good explanation too.